# EmguCV Capture Mat error in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, emgucv

I'm trying to get a webcam capture with Unity3d and EmguCV 3.0, but I'm stumbling into some weird problems. To start off, I'm trying to get a simple capture going by doing:

```
Capture cap = new Capture(0);
Mat currentFrame = cap.QueryFrame();
```

But unfortunately this throws an error:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Emgu.CV.Mat' to `Emgu.CV.Mat'
```

That doesn't really make any sense to me, I tried to cast it, but that doesn't work either. The documentation shows the `QueryFrame` returns a `Mat`: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/18b6eba7-f18b-fa87-8bf2-2acff68988cb.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered getting a Color32 array from a webCamTexture with "GetPixels32"?  Could then convert that array into a Mat type (will need to look at the Mat constructors).  I'm in the same boat as you - been trying to get EMGU in Unity to properly export to xcode for an iOS app.

It looks like there is a 'Mat.SetTo(data)' which takes an array and applies the data to the mat instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the implicit convert error, but you can get things going with the below code, this should be added to a raw image UI object:

```
private WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
private Color32[] colors;

private int width = 640;
private int height = 480;

private Texture2D tex;
private byte[] bytes;

void Start ()
{
WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
int cameraCount = devices.Length;

if (cameraCount > 0)
{
    webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(devices[0].name, width, height);
    webcamTexture.Play();

    colors = new Color32[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];
    bytes = new byte[colors.Length*3];

    tex = new Texture2D (webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = tex;

    CvInvoke.CheckLibraryLoaded();
}
else {
    Debug.LogError("No Camera found!");
}
}

void Update ()
{
if (webcamTexture.didUpdateThisFrame) {

    webcamTexture.GetPixels32(colors);

    GCHandle imageHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(colors, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    GCHandle matHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    using(Image<Bgra, byte> image = new Image<Bgra, byte>(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height, webcamTexture.width * 4, imageHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject())){
        using(Mat mat = new Mat(webcamTexture.height, webcamTexture.width, DepthType.Cv8U, 3, matHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), webcamTexture.width*3)){
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, mat, ColorConversion.Bgra2Bgr);
        }
    }
    imageHandle.Free();
    matHandle.Free();

    tex.LoadRawTextureData(bytes);
    tex.Apply();
}
```

The next challenge is to convert the Bgra image to a Gray image, by changing the conversion method and depth type I can get an image, but it is 1/3th the width...

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to your problem.

```
Capture capWebcam = new Capture();
Image<Bgr, byte> imgSceneColor = capWebcam.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
```

When you need a Mat() from imgSceneColor you can just use the .Mat property like this.

```
Mat imgMat = imgSceneColor.Mat;
```

Comment: Cool thanks, but unfortunately this throws an error in line with my original one: `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte>' to 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte>'` I guess this is some kind of Unity3D problem

Comment: This is a strange error.  Have you confirmed that all your Emgu assemblies are the same version?  I say that because CS0029 is about not being able to convert one data type to another data type.  Clearly, in both your examples, the data types appear to be the same.  My Emgu is 3.0.2158 and OpenCV dlls are named with 300 and haven't had these problems.